# drupal commerce product types

Tags: 7, entities, nodes, commerce

I'm kind of confused with the product types. Lets say I have 2 products, a laptop and a desktop PC. Both have "brand" as a field. Would I have to create 2 product types or is there a way to have a default product type and apply the extra product typ

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a product of type "computer".
2. Then create a list field in "computer" called "computer type", where you can specify "desktop" or "laptop".

You can have another list field named "brand" on the computer product.